# How to transfer FileStorage object via FTP in python

Tags: python, web-services, flask, ftp, sftp

I have a rester webservice (`Flask Webservice`) where clients sends me file object(Image or pdf); Now I want to store it into FTP location. How can I store file object(Image or pdf) to FTP location.

I am using `Flask Webservice(Rester API)`, I able to receive file objct of type `FileStorage`. then I trying to store the file object(Image or pdf) to FTP using `paramiko` API `paramiko.SFTPClient class` to transfer/store the file to FTP. But it is not accepting the file object. It is expecting only local file path. 
Below is the sample code which is used to transfer file to FTP

**FTP Code:**

```
import paramiko
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.put(localpath, filepath)
```

Could you please suggest me how can I achieve file object store to FTP?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to save your FileStorage object on disk, and then give the path to paramiko sftp client (your `localpath` variable).

Note that this is a non-optimised solution since it requires to write data on disk then re-read it.

---

For a more optimised solution, according to [paramiko's SFTP doc](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#putfo), you could use the method

> putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size=0, callback=None, confirm=True)

That would replace your line `sftp.put(localpath, filepath)` by `sftp.putfo(filestorage_object, filepath)`